# Fixing Multiindex after unstack

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

month = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
c = [1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 0]
itemIDs = [5,1,1,4,5,2,2,2]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=month)
df.columns = ["month"]
df["partition"] = b
df["value"] = c
df["id"] = itemIDs
print(df)
print("")
# df=df.pivot(index="month",columns="partition",values="value")
df= df.groupby(["id","month","partition"]).agg(value=pd.NamedAgg(column="value",aggfunc="sum")).unstack("partition",fill_value=0)
df.reset_index(inplace=True,level=0)
df.columns= df.columns.droplevel()
df.to_csv("test.csv",index=False)
print(df)
```

My goal is to sum all values for each id in each month for each partition and transpose the partitions in each (id,month) group.

The above code is a combination of all tipps I could find on Stackoverflow, but my issue now is that the index is not being computed properly. I would expect the folowing index:

id,month,1,2,3,4

where the numbers 1-4 are a result of the transpose/unstack operation.

The actual result is (without droplevel):
[image]

Anybody know how to fix this? I know there are a lot of multiindex questions, but all those I have looked into did not work for me (it is possible I might have used them incorrectly, but am desperate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For avoid `MultiIndex` in columns is added `value` after `agg` for selecting column `value` to `Series`, last is added [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for `MultiIndex in index` to columns and [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for remove columns names, here text `partition`:

```
df = (df.groupby(["id","month","partition"])
        .agg(value=pd.NamedAgg(column="value",aggfunc="sum"))['value']
        .unstack("partition",fill_value=0)
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
# df.to_csv("test.csv",index=False)
print(df)
   id  month  1  2  3  4
0   1      1  0  0  0  0
1   2      2  0  3  3  0
2   4      1  0  0  0  1
3   5      1  3  0  0  0
```